# 403 error page not working with F flag in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, httpforbiddenhandler

I'm trying to only allow https connections to a subdomain of mine. My .htaccess looks like this currently:

```
Options -MultiViews -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteEngine On
#Only allow https requests
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/docs/?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
#Docs file rewrite
RewriteRule ^docs/?$ /Docs.php
```

If I remove the `Only allow https requests` section and try to access a directory (e.g. `http://foo.bar.com/images/`), I am displayed my pretty 403 page. But if I leave that section in and go to the subdomain root (e.g. `http://foo.bar.com/`), I get the default error page, is this something to do with htaccess completely forbidding access to all files?

Examples:
Through a secure connection the 403 page works  - https://api.subjectplanner.co.uk/assets
But through a non secure one, it is the default page - http://api.subjectplanner.co.uk/assets

Answer (score 1):

`RewriteEngine On` should be before you use rewrite rules:

```
Options -MultiViews -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteEngine On

#Only allow https requests
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule !^docs - [NC,F]

RewriteRule ^docs/?$ /Docs.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: That still results in the default page being displayed. I have now included some examples within my question, maybe you could look at those.

Comment: `http://api.subjectplanner.co.uk/assets` shows 403 (forbidden) error which is due to this rule in place since rule works for `non-https` only.

Comment: Also remember that 1st rule above doesn't impact `https` request.

Comment: @anubhava, googling always gives your answers on top in htaccess sir :) cheers :)